# Bulk Write in MongoEngine

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

MongoDB and PyMongo both supports bulk write or inserting multiple documents at once.
MongoDB:

```
db.collection_name.insertMany()
```

PyMongo:

```
collection.insert([list_of_objects])
```

But I couldn't find anything similar in MongoEngine for the same purpose. There are multiple approaches but all inserts one item at a time. So is there really nothing similar like this? Since mongoengine is built top on PyMongo.

> My requirement is that I have huge data data to insert at a time but since processing every document takes time so that I have to do blind insert for performance. PyMongo has the functionality to do that so if mongoengine don't have anything similar is it possible to use the pymongo instance of mongoengine for this only?

Comment: According to the documentation, `insert` is capable of bulk inserting documents: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.insert

Comment: To use `insert` I have to convert every dict object to Model object for the same. But mongoengine has a method `ModelName(**dict_name).save()` which save the the `dict_name` in mongodb. I am finding something similar where I can insert a list of dict objects.

Comment: `save()` sounds like a ORM method. In ORM, you have a one-to-one mapping of DB objects to Python objects. How do you expect to bulk under such a scenario?

Comment: Okay so is there any other such way to do this? @rdas

Comment: Just use `insert()`.

Comment: *"Technically"*, the `insert()` method itself was considered deprecated some time ago. MongoEngine is basically using the [`pymongo`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/) driver, and the `insert()` there is effectively the `insert_many()` method, and really just "aliased". It's always taken an array of documents as an argument, even before the naming change.

Comment: You might also note there is an undocumented method on ANY model in MongoEngine, which is `._get_collection()`. This actually gets the `Collection` object from the underlying pymongo driver, and allows you to access it's methods directly. Providing you have a recent pymongo ( last couple of years really ) installed, then you have full access to any collection methods though that. i.e `bulk_write()`, `insert_many()` etc.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks that worked. But this thing would be simple if mongoengine had the functionality

Comment: So the two things there are **1.** Not *really* that regularly maintained, as I did note that the MongoEngine code does directly use `insert()` even when that has been deprecated for some time. **2.** It *"kind of"* goes against the ethos of what MongoEngine was written for. And by that I mean the expected usage to be a lot more *"djangoesque"* than by what the core driver exposes directly. If you really feel that strongly about it, then put your hand up as a contributor and submit a pull request. Note again that deprecated does not mean "gone". Both methods in this case do the same thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For bulk insert, you've got 2 options:

1) **Pymongo**

If your `dict`'s are formatted in the exact shape as they should be stored, then use pymongo, you'll get much better performance as you'll save on the overhead of the ORM/ODM library (objects instantiation, validation, etc).

As stated in the comments, you can access the `pymongo.Collection` that's behind a Model class with `Model._get_collection()`.

The Added value is performance, the downside is that if any documents is malformed (e.g missing field, missing default value, wrong type, additional field, etc), it will get inserted anyway since you are bypassing MongoEngine. And you may have surprises later on when interacting with the data through your Model.

2) **MongoEngine**

If you have an array of Model instances, then you can do the bulk insert in `MongoEngine` using:

```
Model.objects.insert(your_array)
```

If you can construct your object with `Model(**dict).save`, then that means that you can do

```py
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField()
    age = IntField(default=32)

array = [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Hulk', 'age': 100}]
person_instances = [Person(**data) for data in array]

Person.objects.insert(person_instances, load_bulk=False)

# Would insert the following
#[{'_id': ObjectId('...'), 'age': 32, 'name': 'John'},
# {'_id': ObjectId('...'), 'age': 100, 'name': 'Hulk'}]
```

Advantage is that it guarantees that the format of the documents you insert are valid with your MongoEngine Model (in my example that means accounting for the default value of `age` when its not in the dict). The downside is that there is a performance cost.

In short, it all depends if your primary need is performance or if you can live with MongoEngine's overhead.

Comment: Is it possible to modify multiple documents with multiple fields at the same time using mongo engine. Asked as a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71628518/modifying-multiple-documents-with-multiple-fields-in-mongodb-using-mongo-engine

Comment: @imhans4305 the link does not work